# Stripe - global is not defined

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, stripe-payments, ionic4

I have a problem when I want to use the stripe API.

Environnement :

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.20",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.23",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.1.1",
    "@types/node": "^8.9.5",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3"
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.1",
    "stripe": "^8.32.0",
  },
```

Node version : 13.7.0

### My problem

> capability.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined

From the moment I use:

```
import Stripe from 'stripe';
const stripe = new Stripe('sk_test_...', {
  apiVersion: '2020-03-02',
});
```

I tried (in my index.html or Polyfills) :

```
(window as any).global = window;
global.Buffer = global.Buffer || require('buffer').Buffer;
(window as any).process = {
  version: ''
};
```

Lots of things like that but always mistakes.

I also put **Stripe.js** in my **index.html** but still nothing.

Can you help me ?

Comment: Shouldn't `const stripe = new Stripe(` be `const stripe = Stripe(`?

Comment: Actually window is not defined, which you are getting.

Comment: @KurtHamilton If I don't put  `New` it triggers an error

Error : 


`The value of type 'typeof Stripe' cannot be called. Do you want to include 'new'?`

Comment: @DeepKakkar Do you have more details?

Comment: window is not a global defined variable in node js.

Comment: @MickaelAlias Ah, I see you're using the Stripe npm package. I use Stripe elements in my Angular project, and the setup is a bit different

Comment: Can you share the logs too.

Comment: @KurtHamilton Okey ! What are the differences? Do you have an example or tutorial ?

Comment: I just followed the official docs: https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js. I'm not sure the stripe npm package is for use on the client?

Comment: @KurtHamilton Ok I'll try ! Thank's

Answer (score 0):

I remember tackling this a while ago, i created a shim file and imported it into polyfills. I can't remember why but i seem to remember that you couldn't just do this directly in the polyfills.ts file.

**Shim file**

```
(window as any).global = window;
```

**Polyfills.ts**

```
import './global-shim';
```